# Authentication to Azure-AD using Cordova

Tags: azure, cordova, authentication

I am trying to implement a user login system on Cordova using a component that it offers. I am very new to Cordova so I would really appreciate any help! 
I could see that one component that has been used before is deprecated.
I couldn't really find something relevant, only on Microsoft website, however, they are not very detailed on their tutorials.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Authentication to Azure AD? SSO? Can you add more details to your question?

Comment: @Hackerman actually as login as I know AD is used for Cordova. I don't know anything about SSO. As I mentioned any suggestion would do. Thanks!